# How do you disable NetBIOS traffic on Mac OS?

Tags: networking, macos

I noticed after running Responder on my internal network that my MacBook Pro Mojave is sending out NetBIOS name query requests looking for `__MSBROWSE__` and WORKGROUP which Responder will send a poisoned request to. I know `__MSBROWSE__` should be held by the NetBIOS domain master browser and WORKGROUP is the default domain all Windows operating systems are initially tied to but I would like to disable this behavior on my MacBook Pro. I have tried to disable and unload the NetBIOS daemon with the following commands but still noticed the same behavior.

```
sudo launchctl disable system/netbiosd
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.netbiosd.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.netbiosd.plist
```

`com.apple.netbiosd.plist` and `com.apple.netbiosd.plist` did not exist so the first command successful while the last two failed. I have also created the following file and added the text in the command below:

```
printf "[default]\nport445=no_netbios\n" | sudo tee /etc/nsmb.conf >/dev/null
```

Comment: This [link](https://www.tecklyfe.com/disable-netbios-macos-os-x/) has the commands you have tried, plus one extra step, to create a file called `nsmb.conf`. Would that fit the bill do you think?

Comment: I edited the original question with an update.

Comment: So netbios is required if you do any kind of sharing on the mac, and is also used by bonjour. I think in the newer systems, mDNSResponder uses bonjour too - so you could try disabling that, but you may lose some 'easy-mode' network connectivity tools.  Try `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist NoMulticastAdvertisements -bool YES`